# Unable to go to definition using jedi-vim plugin on packages installed using pip install --user

Tags: pip, jedi-vim

I am able to *goto definitions* of functions imported from a package using jedi-vim when the package is installed in following directory:

> /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/

However when it is installed in the following directory, using *pip install --user package_name*, goto definition fails with error: **jedi-vim: Couldn't find any definitions for this**.

> $HOME/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages

import of package works in both cases.

Do I need additional configuration with jedi-vim to make sure that it jumps the definition even when the package is installed in $HOME/.local/lib/python2.7/ directory?

Comment: That is potentially an issue in jedi-vim, please add it to jedi-vim's issue tracker!

Comment: Created the issue: https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi-vim/issues/744

Answer (score 0):

Change all "safe=True" to "safe=False"( three times,to be exactly) in

```
~/.vim/bundle/jedi-vim/pythonx/jedi/jedi/api/environment.py
```

solved the problem for me.

Hope this can be useful.

Some relate links:

https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi-vim/issues/869

https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi-vim/issues/744